# How to setup RDP connection to a Linux (Ubuntu Server) VM in Azure using SSH tunnel?

Tags: linux, ssh, azure, rdp, ssh-tunnel

I am reading https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/use-remote-desktop and is stuck at the following passage:
[image]

> Specifying a password does not update your SSHD configuration to permit password logins if it currently does not. From a security perspective, you may wish to connect to your VM with an SSH tunnel using key-based authentication and then connect to xrdp. If so, skip the following step on creating a network security group rule to allow remote desktop traffic.

I wish Microsoft elaborated here, because I have no idea how to do it.

Given that I can connect to my VM with SSH using key based authentication how can I setup RDP to connect using the SSH tunnel?

**Clarification**

I have landed onto this article while searching how to configured RDP to my Linux machine. Like installing all kinds of software and authentication. However, the article does not elaborate how to setup an SSH tunnel, just mentions it is an option. I do want to use SSH tunnel, but I do not know how.

Comment: I am unsure what you are confused about and why you are highlighting that section if you plan on using key-based authentication to connect to the remote. If you are using key-based-auth that section is irrelevant. I am not sure why you are looking at that article since it isn't about using RDP via a tunnel.

Comment: Please, see my clarification

Comment: Did you try a simple google search for [ssh tunnel rdp](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+tunnel+rdp) or [ssh port forwarding tunnel](https://www.google.com/search?q=ssh+port+forwarding+tunnel)? This is a topic well covered in other questions on stack exchange, and via search. The exact details depend on your client. Since you haven't mentioned it, you probably should just review some of the search results.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Bitvise SSH Client. (https://www.bitvise.com/download-area)

I do not work for them, but I have used their products for several years now.

Their SSH client makes it ridiculously easy to do this.  Once an SSH connection is established, a single click can open an RDP session.

I've not used it specifically with Azure, but I have used it with other VM-hosted Windows machines.  I've been very happy with its performance.

You can always tunnel RDP through a normal SSH client (ie. putty, ssh.com, etc). but the Bitvise client does make it easy, especially if you aren't all that familiar with the underlying technologies.